# Obtaining the current URL inline in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to implement the Facebook Like button on my site, but rather than having to add it to each individual page, I would rather add it once to the master page and use the current URL. I have tried the following code to obtain the current URL:

```
<a href="<% Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString(); %>">Link</a>
```

However, when it runs, say on http://localhost:1234/About.aspx, the link only points to http://localhost:1234 rather than the full address.

What am I doing wrong, or is it not possible to achieve it this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to write a text inline with the HTML from a server code tag, you need to do a Response.Write since a server code tag `<% %>` for asp.net only reads a code inside of it.  To write it in the HTML wither put it in `Response.Write` method or `<%= %>` tag.

```
<a href="<% Response.Write(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString()); %>">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<%=Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString() %>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a href="<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString(); %>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>">Link</a>
```

should work.